# Submitting extension to Safari Extension Gallery

Tags: safari, appstore-approval, safari-extension

I've built a safari extension but it seems like a black box in terms of submitting to the Safari Extension Gallery. I've googled it and looked at the Apple documentation but there are still several points that are unclear to me:

1) Does Safari Extension Gallery host the extension (i.e. like Chrome Web Store) or do I need to self host?

2) In the submit form, it ask for the URL. So if Apple does self host, can I just upload the built extension package to dropbox and give the dropbox URL in the form?

3) After submitting to the Extension Gallery, how long does it take for it to be approved? I heard 2-3 weeks, which is ridic compared to the 5 mins Chrome approval!

Comment: I encounter the same situation. It's weird that they claim hosting the extension and ask for the download URL the same time.

Comment: Hi @harryngh, what did you do at the end? How long did you have to wait for?